# How to change kernel options on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kernel

I am to install Dummynet and according to this manpage http://goo.gl/qqjwfg I have to make the following changes in the kernel configuration file:

```
       options IPFIREWALL
       options DUMMYNET
       options HZ=1000
```

How do I access the kernel configuration file to make these changes? Please help.

Comment: The solution to this problem can be found in the following 
[link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/kconfig.html)